# visual studio online VSTS Build - Mirror clone repository not working

Tags: git, azure-pipelines

I am currently using the VSTS Build system to make a nightly mirror clone of a 3rd party repository (which I have genuine access to).

I am essentially performing the following in sequence:

```
git clone --mirror [repository_url]
cd [respository]
git remote add <new_remote> [new_remote_url]
git push [new_remote_url] --mirror -force
```

When I perform these steps from a git bash terminal on my development PC, it works no problem, I can see the mirror cloned repository in my new_remote_url repository with all changes/history/etc.

Some sample output is as such when done on my dev machine:

```
2016-12-28T12:11:37.3149001Z  * [new branch]      tests/ios -> tests/ios
2016-12-28T12:11:37.3149001Z  * [new branch]      tests/sprint-8 -> tests/sprint-8
2016-12-28T12:11:37.3149001Z ##[section]Finishing: Push remote --all
```

Now when I try to perform these same steps as a sequence of CMD tasks via VSTS nightly build, the build itself completes, and 'appears' to work - but when I check my repository it says it is empty? (BUt under the hood it actually isn't).

The difference seems to be that the VSTS version is pre-fixing the GIT remote name on to the front of the branches, this doesn't appear to work correctly and ends up with the repository looking empty from the GUI - but if I then re-run the script from my local development PC it will delete these Branches before re-importing them correctly named.

The output from the final git push task in VSTS is pretty much along these lines:

> 2016-12-28T12:11:37.3149001Z  * [new branch]      origin/tests/ios ->
>   origin/tests/ios
>       2016-12-28T12:11:37.3149001Z  * [new branch]      origin/tests/sprint-8 -> origin/tests/sprint-8
>       2016-12-28T12:11:37.3149001Z ##[section]Finishing: Push remote --all

Is there a reason why the same script would be pre-fixing in such a way within VSTS build system?

Comment: I made a test (GitHub repository to VSTS git reprository) with VSTS build system with Hosted agent, I can't reproduce that issue and there isn't pre-fixing the git remote name on the front of the branches. What're your 3rd party repository and target repository? Can you share the whole build log on the OneDrive? You can try to create a new repository and push to this new repository and check the result.

Comment: What're the detail build steps and arguments of your build definition?

Comment: Hey, the build steps are literally as defined above - 4 CMD line tool executions in a row.

Comment: Hey, the build steps are literally as defined above - 4 CMD line tool executions in a row. The external repository is a BitBucket GIT which I have full access to.

Also I am using the hosted agent too, what seems to be happening is that the repository *is* actually ported over, but because it is trying to automatically be inserted with a branch name of origin/tests/ios for example - it doesn't show up in the VSTS web portal and says it is empty. I am assuming the origin/ part of the branch path is the problem. What steps did you take to clone it? also did you use --mirror?

Comment: My build steps (3 Command line steps): 1, Tool: git, Arguments: clone --mirror https://github.com/xingyu217/VSTSTest.git test, Working folder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory); 2, Tool: git, Arguemnts: remote add mirrorrepo https://xing:$(System.AccessToken)@starain.visualstudio.com/ScrumGitStarain/_git/MirrorRepo5, Working folder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\test; 3, Tool: git, Arguments: push mirrorrepo --mirror –force, Working directory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\test. I removed cd [respository] (not working for me), using working directory instead. I will try it with BitBucket.

Comment: I made a test with BitBucket, it works fine too. Try to make a test with my steps and check the result. On the other hand, can you share the whole build log on the OneDrive?

Comment: I would have to strip out quite a lot of sensitive information, but I am going to try to re-produce the build with your set of steps tonight and will see if it works, thanks for the input so far - hopefully your set of steps will go some way to resolving it.

Comment: Thank you very much, this 3-step process does indeed work. It seems the different was using the $Build.SourcesDirectory as the working dir instead of doing changedir as a cmd line step. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Starain-MSFT kindly pointed out, the difference that got it working was to use the VSTS Advanced setting within the build to set the working folder to the Build Sources Directory, instead of manually performing a cmd line changedir step.

The only change was in the first step of cloning the repository whereby I now specify an explicit directory name for use in the later commands advanced settings.